# ATG Dynamo - Not able to get installable for ATG 9.1

Tags: atg

I want to start working with ATG Commerce. I tried to downloaded from the link: https://edelivery.oracle.com/EPD/Search/handle_go
Looking at the compatibility, I want to work with ATG 9.1, JBoss 4.2.0, JDK1.5

But I see the only below versions of ATG are available in the above link. I did not find the ATG 9.12. Can you please help with the link where I can get ATG 9.1?

```
Select Description Release Part Number Updated # Parts / Size 
Oracle ATG Web Commerce (2007.4) Media Pack for Microsoft Windows 2007.4.0.0.0 B65809-01 DEC-30-2011 10 /1.9G 
Oracle ATG Web Commerce (10.0.3) Media Pack for Microsoft Windows 10.0.3.0.0 B64715-01 NOV-02-2011 11 /2.8G 
Oracle ATG Web Commerce (9.4) Media Pack for Microsoft Windows 9.4.0.0.0 B65233-01 NOV-09-2011 12 /2.6G
```

Answer (score 3):

ATG 9.4 is the only 9.X version Oracle is supporting.  You can probably find 9.1 if you ask around, people will likely have installers.  9.4 *should* work pretty closely with 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for ATG.. use the latest one (10.1 as of now), the new versions are more feature rich.
If there is any specific reason for using jboss 4 and jdk 1.5 then its a different story.